# Protego Causa in Sanctus and In causa Sanctus

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

How can I say "I'm in a saint cause"or "a noble cause".

Like studying for example, or acquiring knowledge in science is a noble cause, so I can say that I'm pursuing or I'm in the middle of a "saint cause".

All I have in my mind with my basic latin knowledge is "IN CAVSA SANCTA SVM".

But then I remembered the "PROTEGO CAVSA IN SANCTVS" sentence in March of the Templars. Is it the same ? Or each has a different signification

Thank you !